# importing from higher directories in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

How do I import from a higher level directory in python.

For example:

I have project/lib/lib.py
project/stuff/main.py

i want to import lib.py in main.py

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like:

```
from ..lib import lib
```

Answer (score 0):

standard method is to add project to your path and do

```
import lib.lib
```

You will need a file called `__init__.py` in the lib folder as well, which can be blank.